# Ruby on Rails Rspec migrates database when running rake spec:plugins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rspec

I'm trying to test a plugin that i wrote by running:

```
rake spec:plugins
```

When i execute this command it appears that it drops my database tables (in my test DB) and then runs a migration without any plugins loaded to give me a clean database. This would normally be fine, but I am using a plugin that allows me to set index length limits for MYSQL, so if I run a migration without that plugin, then i get a syntax error. This means that i cannot test my plugin with the rspec rake command.

I can't find any documentation for this command, is there a way to get it to not run any migrations before it executes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this in your plugin spec:

```
Spec::Runner.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

Of course this means you have to ensure the test DB is in the correct state for your tests, and that you clean up any modifications on exit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i eventually just gave up and ran that spec file directly.